# Manually throw an exception

Tags: java

How would I manually throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in Java and optionally print a message?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: [How to throw exceptions (Java tutorials)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html)

Answer (score 32):

You simply:

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("your message goes here");
```

If you need to print that message, do so from where you catch the exception. (You can reach the message with the `getMessage()` method.)

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("If you want a message, put it here");
```

This doesn't actually print the message; it just prepares it. To print the message, do something like the following:

```
try {
    //...
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("If you want a message, put it here");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

In the future, I'd suggest looking around for an answer before posting.

Comment: What, no `int[] arr = new int[10]; arr[10];`? :P

Comment: @Kublai Khan I tried posting that on a similar question and it just got downvoted.

Comment: Yeah I know - I was one of the downvoters (humor/olive branch)

Comment: @Kublai Khan LOL I just got that! :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use the throw statement to throw an exception. The throw statement requires a single argument: a throwable object. Throwable objects are instances of any subclass of the Throwable class. Here's an example of a throw statement.

```
throw someThrowableObject;
```

Example:

```
    public void example() {
       try{
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
       } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```